# Null Exception in App constructor when starting Prism 7 application

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I upgraded a xamarin forms application to use prism 7. When the app starts (android project), it crashes on this line

```
public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }
```

The error is

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
```

This happens with the prerelease and also with the current latest version from myget: 7.0.0.343-ci.

I did not get this error with prism 6.3.

App.xaml.cs:

```
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Ninject;
using SunBaseApp.Helpers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlCompilation(Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

namespace SunBaseApp
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/LoginPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            var cont = containerRegistry.GetKernel();

            cont.Bind<IAppSettings>().To<AppSettings>().InSingletonScope();
            cont.Bind<IDataService>().To<DataService>().InSingletonScope();

            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginPageModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SettingsEditPage, SettingsEditPageModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<StatPage, StatPageModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<WebsiteListPage, WebsiteListPageModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<WebsiteEditPage, WebsiteEditPageModel>();
        }
    }    
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Ninject;assembly=Prism.Ninject.Forms"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                        x:Class="SunBaseApp.App">

  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Color x:Key="WindowBackgroundColor">#97D3F3</Color>
      <Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor">Green</Color>
      <Color x:Key="ButtonTextgroundColor">White</Color>
      <Color x:Key="textColor">Black</Color>

      <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColor}" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonTextgroundColor}" />
      </Style>

      <!--<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Green"/>
      </Style>-->

      <!--<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColor}" />
      </Style>-->

    </ResourceDictionary>   </Application.Resources>

</prism:PrismApplication>
```

Mainactivity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;

namespace SunBaseApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SunBaseApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon2", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));

            UserDialogs.Init(this);
        }

        public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
        {
            public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that Ninject has some issues running on Droid. I would suggest that you update your project to use another more stable container. Also keep in mind that with the latest you do not need to reference the container directly unless you require a more advanced registration. Something basic like what you have can be simply registered like:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
```

Comment: Thank you Dan! I switched to DryIoc and it is working again. Also applied the simpler registration.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as Ed S. Is there any other hint you could give instead of switching the IoC Container? @Dan S.

Comment: @TobiasTheel Ninject is no longer a supported container for Prism

Comment: Do you have any source for that? Sounds like i should not start to use Prism.

Comment: Do I have a source for what exactly?

Comment: That awkward moment when you don't realise you're talking to a Prism developer...